# Как правильно сверстать блок адаптивно?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

[image]

Как правильно сверстать такой блок, чтоб он хорошо отображался при адаптивности?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самое простое - на svg:

```html
<svg style="width: 100%; max-width: 400px; height: 100%; max-height: 400px;" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
  <circle cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#dfe8ed" stroke-width="3"></circle>
  <circle cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#30bae7" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="90 10" stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>
  <text x="30%" y="58%" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: .7em">90</text>
  <text x="60%" y="57%" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: .4em">%</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

CSS вариант:

```css
skill, skill:before, skill:after {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

skill {
  background: radial-gradient(circle, #fff 40px, #eee 41px, #eee 48px, #fff 49px);
}

skill:before {
  content: '';
  background: radial-gradient(circle, #fff 40px, #ade 41px, #ade 48px, #fff 49px);
  clip-path: polygon(50px 50px, 50px 0, 100px 0, 100px 100px, 0 100px, 0 0, 10px 0);
}

skill:after {
  content: '90%';
  font: 30px Arial;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<skill />
```